# A Relevance & Purpose Question

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Question Number 6 is really confusing. I understood that we should not add this sentence because it is unrelated.

CORRECT ANSWER: C

If the sentence which is to be added contained information related to actual needs and wants, we might have given a consideration. However, the actual problem is the explanation:

Why C? Why not D?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about learning English.  It is about understanding the psychology of this particular test and what it measures.

Comment: "They were addicted to snacking on caviar and wearing fancy robes". LOL

Answer (score 1):

This is not a question about English.  This is a question about the psychology of this test, and what kind of answers the test-writers want you to pick as "correct".

In my opinion all of the answer choices are valid, the question is which is *most consistent* with the correct answers to other, similar questions.  The test-writers seem to be teaching as much as testing, in this case the lesson is that a passage should be focused on a single, coherent narrative or argument, and not introduce irrelevant or distracting elements.

Frankly, this is a stupid question because it is not focused on a single, simple answer.  Why would the writer want to introduce something about caviar?  Did medieval nobles really eat caviar?  Without refrigeration, how did the nobles get the caviar? Or are we suddenly talking only about nobles that live near coastlines that support the kind of fish that produce good caviar?  Why use the word "addicted"?  Who is this writer and why is he or she so scatterbrained?

I've seen many other tests (like the US law school entrance exam) that test whether you understand the concept of a "focused paragraph or argument", but they have been carefully designed to avoid nonsense.  These tests suggest options that *seem* relevant but which are off-topic for a variety of standard reasons.  Here is an example:

> *During the construction of the Quebec Bridge in 1907, the bridge’s designer, Theodore Cooper, received word that the suspended span being built out from the bridge’s cantilever was deflecting downward by a fraction of an inch (2.54 centimeters). Before he could telegraph to freeze the project, the whole cantilever arm broke off and plunged, along with seven dozen workers, into the St. Lawrence River. It was the worst bridge construction disaster in history. As a direct result of the inquiry that followed, the engineering “rules of thumb” by which thousands of bridges had been built around the world went down with the Quebec Bridge. Twentieth-century bridge engineers would thereafter depend on far more rigorous applications of mathematical analysis.*
>
> Which one of the following statements can be properly inferred from the passage?
>
> 1. Bridges built before about 1907 were built without thorough mathematical analysis and, therefore, were unsafe for the public to use.
> 2. Cooper’s absence from the Quebec Bridge construction site resulted in the breaking off of the cantilever.
> 3. Nineteenth-century bridge engineers relied on their rules of thumb because analytical methods were inadequate to solve their design problems.
> 4. Only a more rigorous application of mathematical analysis to the design of the Quebec Bridge could have prevented its collapse.
> 5. Prior to 1907 the mathematical analysis incorporated in engineering rules of thumb was insufficient to completely assure the safety of bridges under construction.

The answer here is #5, because all of the other answer choices introduce new or speculative information.

Again, figuring out the answer to the question in your test requires you to understand what, exactly, is the point of these kind of questions. Unfortunately, we cannot help you with that.  You need to find someone who does understand this psychology and who can explain the underlying logic.